# Set width and height based on dimentions of parent's parent Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview, horizontalscrollview

I'm dynamicly adding ImageViews in a LinearLayout witch is inside a HorizontalScrollView.

Now I want to set the width and height of these ImageViews based on the parent LinearLayout of this HorizontalScrollView.

This is my xml (information_imagescrollview_item.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my code:

```
View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.information_imagescrollview_item, container, false);
LinearLayout scrollViewLayout = (LinearLayout) contentView.findViewById(R.id.linear);
for(Object intObj : page.content) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.getContext());
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable((int) intObj);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
    scrollViewLayout.addView(imageView);
}
page.addView(contentView);
```

How can I set each imageView to have the same width and height as the parentlayout in the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change a dynamic view's dimensions by code. So I would bet you should change the `ImageView`'s layout parameters in the `for` loop before adding it to your LinearLayout like this:

```
for(Object intObj : page.content) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this.getContext());
    Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable((int) intObj);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
    //Changing height...
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    //...and width
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    scrollViewLayout.addView(imageView);
}
```

This will set the `ImageView`'s width and height to the containing (parent) `LinearLayout`'s width and height.

Comment: If I add imageView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; the image is still almost twice the screenwidth.

Comment: Do you want to scroll the images one after another like in a gallery app?

Comment: Yes. But in between a couple of textviews,

Comment: Can I ask you to send a link of a sketch or update your answer with it? I don't want to keep guessing what you really would like to create...